# Classification/weather prediction

Tags: r, classification, prediction, weather

I am currently studying weather prediction using R.

I tried `rpart` but some of the predictions are removed.

My data contains Weather, Humidity, and Temperature can be found on the link,

[Weather Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14z7PKThn3Tmmn2JQGH-UVfuHSI-FCivdHj2bs4-sg0E/edit?usp=sharing).

I just want to create ranges for the prediction like:

> Haze = Temperature is 27 to 29 & Humidity is 72 to 76

for all the data under weather. What is the best thing to do?

Comment: I'm trying to know the range to categorize that this temperature and this humidity is a haze.

Comment: Can you not just look at the distributions of temp and humidity where your response variable = Haze? I'm not sure why you need to build a model for this.

Answer (score 0):

expand.grid()` for this issue. 
expand.grid creates all possible combinations from sequences  27:29 and 72 to 76.

See this example

```
expand.grid("Temperature" = 27:29, "Humidity" = 72:76)
```

This can handed over the function predict like this:

```
predict(Yourmodel, newdata = expand.grid(Temperature = 27:29, "Humidity" = 72:76))
```

Comment: I don't know the range. That's what I'm trying to discover in this research.